# Error executing Select Into Statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following query:

```
DECLARE @ImageName VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @ImageName = '[User:AvatarUrl(userid=3)]'

INSERT INTO Profile_Images (UserID, ImageName)
SELECT UserID, @ImageName 
FROM EasyDNNNews;
```

The @ImageName is a server side variable that gets resolved at runtime.  If I replace @ImageName with 'Martin' for example it works fine.

The IIS error log reports:

> Message:Error executing query DECLARE @ImageName VARCHAR(MAX) SET @ImageName = '/Portals/0/FacebookProfilePictures/Martin Profile.jpg' INSERT INTO Profile_Images (UserID, ImageName) SELECT UserID, @ImageName FROM EasyDNNNews;

So the @ImageName variable is being resolved by the server.

Thoughts?

Comment: What columns and there types you have in `Profile_Images` table? How you execute this query from IIS? What if execute this query via SSMS?

Comment: What is the column size for the `ImageName` in the `Profile_Images` table?

Comment: Since you are executing multiple statements, you would need to put proper terminators. Try putting a `;` or CRLF after each statement.

Comment: @Arulkumar.... I have two columns in Profile_Images.  UserID - nchar(10) and ImageName - varchar(MAX)

Comment: I am using a tool that enables posts and gets to and from the database.  The server side variable [User:AvatarUrl(userid=3)] could very well be the problem.

The tool I'm referring to is here:  I'll contact them for help and let you all know.
http://www.dnnsharp.com/dnn/modules/custom-dnn-api-endpoint

Comment: I solved this.  I changed the UserID field in SQL from nchar(10) to nvarchar(50) and it worked.  Apparently my data type was incorrect.

Thanks!